# Is it possible to use the Google Classroom Go API to comment on things?

Tags: go, google-classroom, google-api-go-client

I'm wondering if there's a way to comment on a Google Classroom assignment/post through the Google Classroom API (specifically the [Go client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/tree/master/classroom/v1)). I've searched the docs but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the moment, there is no direct method to do comment on assignment/post in Class API. You can visit [this](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework#top_of_page) to check what available actions is feasible with the current API. You can [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request) and follow the updates in the [official blog](https://cloud.googleblog.com/2015/06/new-ways-to-integrate-with-Google-Classroom.html).

Comment: You can file feature requests here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908

For this specific issue, however, there's already an issue for this here: http://issuetracker.google.com/36882823

I encourage you to follow this issue for updates. I also recommend clicking “Me too!” at the top of the listed issue and posting comments with your specific use cases.